# angularjs directive not working in mobile app but works in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i've created a angularjs directive to allow only albhabetic characters,numbers and dash(-) in my input fields. SO far it works for only alphabatic characters and numbers only. Still i cant enter dash in my phonegap android application. Why is that?

```
app.directive('onlyAlphabets', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function fromUser(text) {
        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\s]/g, '');

        console.log(transformedInput);
        if (transformedInput !== text) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput; // or return Number(transformedInput)
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$ try that as regex

Comment: it just allows all the characters now :(

Comment: try ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/"

Comment: now i cant enter letters,characters and dash but can enter all other characters. you can check your patten using this

http://plnkr.co/edit/ernsptppPYkEtZzF4Ou5?p=preview

Comment: Isn't your plnkr working right now? This is the pattern currently used `/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\s]/g`.